# What is an equivalent for HttpMessageConverter in Spring WebFlux?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I switch a service from Spring Boot Web MVC to WebFlux.
In this Service is an `HttpMessageConverter` which is used to convert an error object for content type `text/plain` and `text/csv`.

WebFlux ignores the `HttpMessageConverter` and returns HTTP Error Code 406.

So what is the equivalent in WebFlux for the `HttpMessageConverter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. The equvivalent to  the `HttpMessageConverter` in WebFlux is a combination of `ServerCodecConfigurer` and `Encoder`.

Instead of creating a `HttpMessageConverter` bean:

```java
@Bean
public HttpMessageConverter<Error> createXmlHttpMessageConverter() {
    HttpMessageConverter errorConverter = new ErrorPlainTextConverter();
  return errorConverter;
}
```

extend or create a `WebFluxConfigurer` with:

```java
@Override
public void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
  CodecConfigurer.CustomCodecs customCodecs = configurer.customCodecs();
  customCodecs.registerWithDefaultConfig(new ErrorPlainTextConverter());
}
```

and change the converter class from extending `AbstractHttpMessageConverter` to implement `Encoder`.

A good example for an `Encoder` is the [Jaxb2XmlEncoder](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/codec/xml/Jaxb2XmlEncoder.java)